# Set org-capture datetree write on top of the file

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'm using org to store a list of links, I capture the links with org-capture and a custom template, but I want to write the new entries at top of the file. how I can do this?

Comment: See `org-reverse-note-order`.

Comment: Just a note that although the answer recommending `:prepend t` is correct that it ensures new entries are added above older ones, that applies only _within_ a date header. The date headers themselves are still added latest after previous. And `org-reverse-note-order` doesn't change that either. Because the `:prepend t` answer has been marked as accepted, I've asked a similar question to this but specifying more completely what is required. It's [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30584/how-do-i-achieve-reverse-chronology-most-recent-first-in-org-capture-datetree).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Org-Mode Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html), you can add the following template element to your custom captures:

> **:prepend t**
>
> Normally new captured information will be appended at the target location (last child, last table line, last list item...).
>   Setting this property will change that.

See the related post [Using properties in org-mode capture templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116712/using-properties-in-org-mode-capture-templates#11127795), where for example you can achieve the desired effect by using:

```
("w" "Default template" entry (file+headline (concat (file-name-as-directory org-directory) "journal.org") "Notes")
 "* TODO [#C] %^{Title} %?" :prepend t)
```

Comment: by the way, `t` is missing from the manual AFAICT, otherwise `:prepend` alone won't work. This gave me headache couple of days ago.

Comment: @doctorate, I know it is old, but I have just stumbled across this wondering the same thing. All I can guess is that `t` is the value of a `Unit` type. in a functional language, all functions have to have an argument. If your function doesn't need an argument you just define it to receive a `Unit`. I could be wrong, but that is what it seems to me.